# What's wrong with test feature distribution info leakage?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Why is it so bad when we normalize the whole data set and then only split into test and train sets?

I'm getting that our model extract from the normalized data the whole distribution info but I don't understand how it (knowledge of distribution) can entail test data memorization.

Can someone explain it in more detail?

[visual representation of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgCGv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In inference time you will have to use the normalization terms from the train (mean and std). 
So you should do the same in the test set.

Regarding the leakage:

Let’s say that you want to predict the price of a stock (let’s denote it as A) and you use as a feature the price of stock B. 
The feature will be the change in percentage from time stamp t1 to time stamp t2. 
The train set includes the months May-September and the test set is October. 
Assume that October is a very volatile month. If you will normalize the feature by the test data as well, it will change the feature a lot. It means that you gives the model a hint that October is volatile... Then, if course the results of the model will be better... but you give it an information about the future...

Comment: But you didn't say how the leakage happens

Comment: I know how to handle it

Comment: What about now ?